# Does a primitive type multi dimensional array gets casted to Object type in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object

How come

```
int[] arr = new int[5];

Object[] obj = arr;
```

produces a compilation error while

```
int[][] arr = new int[5][5];

Object[] obj = arr;
```

doesn't?

Comment: Because `int[]` is an `Object`, not `Object[]`, whereas an `int[][]` _is_ an `Object[]`. Remember, multidimensional arrays in Java are just arrays of arrays; an array is an `Object`.

Comment: Replace `Object[] obj = arr` with `Object obj = arr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int[]` is an `Object`, so array of `int[]` is an array of `Object`.